# Separate dicts into three lists preserving order based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

Okay maybe my title isn't the best but this is basically my problem:
I have three dicts that look like this:

```
dict1 = {'America': 200, 'Europe': 344, 'Asia': 204, 'Oceania': 38, 'Africa': 14}
dict2 = {'Europe': 394, 'America': 225, 'Asia': 293, 'Oceania': 43, 'Africa': 26}
dict3 = {'Europe': 420, 'America': 250, 'Asia': 363, 'Oceania': 43, 'Africa': 27}
```

What I would like to do is this, split the dictionaries into three lists that is "split" properly based on their key values, so like this:

```
list1 = [200, 344, 204, 38, 14]
list2 = [225, 394, 293, 43, 26]
list3 = [250, 420, 363, 43, 27]
```

EDIT: The desired order = ['America', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Oceania', 'Africa']

Is this easily possible? I have tried a bunch of for-loops but can't preserve order properly.

Comment: I don't understand what order you want there. `list1` has Europe, America, Asia, Oceania, Africa; `list2` and `list3` has America, Europe, Asia, Oceania, Africa. So it seems like you're trying to get the same meaningless arbitrary order from the dict, but then swap the first two values, which I can't imagine why that would be useful.

Comment: The ordering of your examples aren't consistent - what order are you trying to maintain?

Comment: Anything reasonable that you might is pretty easy to do. For example, if you want the values in sorted-key order (`Africa, America, Asia, Europe, Oceania` for all three dicts), that's just `list1 = [dict1[key] for key in sorted(dict1)]`? But you have to first know what order you want, and be able to express it in words, before you (or anyone else) can write the code for it.

Comment: Oh sorry about being unclear about that, the dicts can be ordered any way they want. Edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in method for dictionaries in Python

```
list1 = dict1.values()
```

etc...

results in

```
dict_values([200, 344, 204, 38, 14])
```

Also, you can use list comprehensions

```
list1 = [x for y,x in dict1.items()]
```

results in

```
[200, 344, 204, 38, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the keys is arbitrary, then you need to hardcode it in some iterable. You can then use a list comprehension to get values from keys in the desired order.

```
d1 = {'America': 200, 'Europe': 344, 'Asia': 204, 'Oceania': 38, 'Africa': 14}
d2 = {'Europe': 394, 'America': 225, 'Asia': 293, 'Oceania': 43, 'Africa': 26}
d3 = {'Europe': 420, 'America': 250, 'Asia': 363, 'Oceania': 43, 'Africa': 27}

order = ['America', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Oceania', 'Africa']

list1 = [d1[k] for k in order] # [200, 344, 204, 38, 14]
list2 = [d2[k] for k in order] # [225, 394, 293, 43, 26]
list3 = [d3[k] for k in order] # [250, 420, 363, 43, 27]
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, but I found a better way thanks to another user.

Comment: @PEREZje does the other answer actually preserve order? It should if the dicts were generated the same way using Python3.6+ but it will not in any other case.

Comment: I put the solution as an answer to this post, for my purposes it preserves order. Your method is better if I want a distinct ordering.

Comment: @PEREZje I'm unsure to understand the order you were looking for, but if abarnet's answer worked, then great

Comment: I wasn't really looking for a specific order, merely that the three lists were ordered the same way. @abarnert answer helped for just letting  python "choose" the order, your way is better if I want to choose my own order.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the best solution thanks to @abarnert:

```
list1 = [count_2016[key] for key in sorted(count_2016)]
list2 = [count_2017[key] for key in sorted(count_2017)]
list3 = [count_2018[key] for key in sorted(count_2018)]
```

This preserves the same order for every list.